# Funcion lower y upper case en python

Tags: python

Soy principiante en python y tal vez esta pregunta les parezca sencillas a algunos pero bueno ahí va quería preguntar como podría yo pedir texto por teclado y ese texto que se guarde en automáticamente en mayúsculas?

```
dni = int(input("Ingrese su numero de DNI: "))
nombre = str(input("Ingrese su nombre y apellido: "))
edad = int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
especialidad = str(input("Ingrese especialidad: "))
especialidad.upper()
status = "Disponible"
```

Es en la parte de especialidad no se si funcionara eso,
y si alguien sabe también como hacer para que no identifique acentos, buenisimo, osea si pone acento o no que eso de igual que se guarde sin acento. Asi a la hora de buscarlo en consola es mas fácil encontrarlo. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe una función llamada `replace()` que te permite modificar un texto o un caracter, así puedes cambiar el "á" por "a", aunque más fácil: podrías aplicar lo que es expresiones regulares. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
import re
Patron= '[ÁÉÍÓÚ]'
cadena=str(input("Ingrese cadena: "))
cadena=cadena.upper()
p = re.compile(Patron) 
m = p.search(cadena)
if m:
    print("Tiene tilde",cadena)
else:
    print("No tiene tilde", cadena )
```

Puedes validar, luego de que ingrese la cadena, si tiene tilde, para volver a pedir la cadena al usuario y así él sabrá que no debe ingresar tilde.

Y para hacer que todo sea mayúscula, debes reasignarle el valor que te devuelve `upper()`.

Comment: Lo del upper me sirvio muchisimas gracias anthony y en cuanto a las tildes sabes, lo que quiero lograr es que si alguien escribe por teclado por ejemplo,  "ÁnThÓnY" se guarde en una variable simplemente como "ANTHONY" que quite las tildes.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con remplace(), https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace , aqui está un ejemplo, el problema que encontré es que no puedes cambiar dos cosas, si cambias la "á" -> "a" no podrías cambiar la "é" -> "e", todas las palabras tienen una tilde no más, no dos, pero siempre existe un usuario que quiera poner dos por querer molestar o X razon, para evitar de raiz y validar vocal por vocal, usar mejor Expresiones Regulares, que con un patron donde si puedes poner todas las vocales con mayuscula, validas que no ingrese con tildes, y solo cambias a mayuscula.

Answer (score 1):

Para lo de los acentos y caracteres raros, puedes usar `unidecode`, no viene con python creo, pero lo puedes instalar `pip install unidecode`.

`unidecode` va a tratar de sacar el caracter sin acento más aproximado o parecido al que tiene acento.

```
import unidecode

especialidad = str(input("Ingrese especialidad: "))
especialidad = especialidad.upper()

print(unidecode.unidecode(especialidad))
```

Aunque lo que dice *Anthony Andrés* también está muy bien, es lo más rápido creo ya que no hay import y no tiene tantas cosas como `unidecode`.

Answer (score 0):

La función **upper()** devuelve una copia en mayúsculas de la variable original, pero no la modifica. Sólo te queda reemplazar:

```
especialidad.upper()
```

por esto:

```
especialidad = especialidad.upper()
```

De este modo, asignas el nuevo valor a tu variable original.